# How to use global URLSearchParams in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a (client-side) JavaScript library (a node/angular module).
In this library, I make use of the URLSearchParams class.

```
const form = new URLSearchParams();
form.set('username', data.username);
form.set('password', data.pass);
```

As this is a shared library, it is packed as an npm module.
However, when running a mocha unit test, I get the error that URLSearchParams is not defined. The reason seems to be that node does not have URLSearchParams at the global scope, but has to be imported using `require('url')`:

```
$ node
> new URLSearchParams()
ReferenceError: URLSearchParams is not defined
    at repl:1:5
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:73:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:340:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:538:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

How can I make URLSearchParams available to the client-side code within node, so that I can test the library using mocha?

This is not working:

```
> global.URLSearchParams = require('url').URLSearchParams
undefined
> new URLSearchParams()
TypeError: URLSearchParams is not a constructor
    at repl:1:1
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:73:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:340:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:538:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Comment: https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params

Comment: If I `import 'url-search-params/build/url-search-params';`, I get HTMLAnchorElement is not defined.

Comment: Why don't you import it in the test file?

Answer (score 46):

**Update:** Node v10 has built-in availability of `URLSearchParams` on the global object so it can be used directly as anticipated in the question.

**Older versions of Node:**

One option is to set it as a global in the start-up script of the test runner:

```
import { URLSearchParams } from 'url';
global.URLSearchParams = URLSearchParams
```

With Jest, for example, you would use the [`setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string) to point to the above start-up script.

As a side note, if you wanted to achieve a similar outcome when creating a server-side Webpack bundle of universal code you can achieve this with the Webpack [`ProvidePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/):

```
{
  name: 'server',
  target: 'node',
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      URLSearchParams: ['url', 'URLSearchParams'],
      fetch: 'node-fetch',
    }),
  ],
}
```

Comment: Node v10 has built-in availability of `URLSearchParams` on the `global` object so it can be used without the setups above.

Comment: I have not tested this solution, but thanks for pointing out that Node v10 has this now built in. This solves the question. If you update your answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @MartinNyolt I have updated the answer. If that is what you were after I would appreciate you accepting it.

Answer (score 10):

In AWS Lambda which uses Node8.10, I had to do:

```
const {URLSearchParams} = require('url')
const sp = new URLSearchParams(request.querystring)
```

or

```
const url = require('url')
const sp = new url.URLSearchParams(request.querystring)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to support big range of `nodejs` versions in our application , we could use some dirty code like this :

```
if(typeof URLSearchParams === 'undefined'){
    URLSearchParams = require('url').URLSearchParams;
}
```

Note: It is not best practice to `require` with a condition.

Answer (score 1):

You may use polifill **@ungap/url-search-params** https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ungap/url-search-params and for webpack may use **@ungap/url-search-params/cjs**

Old **NodeJS 8** (which isused in AWS and GCloud) does not support URLSearchParams so this polifill helps.

In **Node 10** when using TypeScript you may enable library *dom* which includes URLSearchParams implementation. Change *tsconfig.json*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      ...
      "dom"
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```