# How to use URLSearchParams in a Node.js and TypeScript project

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a Node.js project that is built with TypeScript I'm trying to use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), however I can see the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'URLSearchParams'.ts(2304)
```

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("foo", 5);
```

---

```
typescript: ^3.9.7
node.js: v12.16.3
```

Comment: @jenson-button-event really i jsut found this works ```import {URLSearchParams} from "url";```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams

Comment: Im confused why i need to import it from "url" when it says "The class is now available on the global object."

Comment: Where do you see this message 'The class is now available on the global object'? Perhaps it only applies to the dom environment, and not node?

Comment: **See Also**: [How to use global URLSearchParams in node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47266550/1366033)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While `URLSearchParams` has lived on the [global object in node](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_urlsearchparams) since `v10.0.0`, it can be hard to pull ambient type information from there.

The `URLSearchParams` class lives in the [`url` module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams), so you can also import it directly from there:

```
import { URLSearchParams } from "url"
```

then use it like this:

```
let queryString = new URLSearchParams({page: "1", pagesize: "100"}).toString();
```

Also, make sure you install types for node

```sh
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

#### Further Reading

- [How to use global URLSearchParams in node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47266550/1366033)